# Is sum of two sequences of independent i.i.d random variables independent?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I am looking for a proof that if I have two sequences of i.i.d random variable that are independent 
$$ (X)^\infty_{n=1}  , (Y)^{\infty}_{n=1}  $$
then its' sum $ (X+Y)_{k} $ is also independent from $ (X+Y)_{m} $ for $ \forall _{m,l} $

I want to use it in a proof that sum of two independent Poisson processes has independent increments and I guess this theorem is general, am I right ?

Comment: Can you clarify?  What is the difference between $(X+Y)_k$ and $(X+Y)_m$?  It sounds like you are describing the same sequence but using a different dummy index.

Comment: e.g $X_1, X_2$ are independent $Y_1, Y_2$ as well but with different distribution. 
Why can I say that $X_1+Y_1 , X_2+Y_2   $ are independent ? I am looking for a general proof with sequence

Comment: Do you mean that if $(X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2)$ are mutually independent, then how to show $(X_1+Y_1)$ and $(X_2+Y_2)$ are independent?

Comment: Yes, i would appreciate proof for 2 sequencies but this case is fine as well.

Comment: In what sense do you see the question on "sequences" being different from the $(X_1,X_2, Y_1, Y_2)$ question I posed above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f,g$ be the common characteristic function of the two i.i.d sequences. For $k \neq m$ we have $Ee^{it(X_k+Y_k)+is(X_m+Y_m)}=f(t)g(t)f(s)g(s)=Ee^{it(X_k+Y_k)}Ee^{is(X_m+Y_m)}$ and this implies that $X_k+Y_k$ is independent of $X_m+Y_m$.